# Sulu CMS 1.6: Is there a possibility to limit the number of images in media_selection?

Tags: sulu

Is there a possibility to limit the number of selectable images for the `media_selection` content type? According to the [documentation](http://docs.sulu.io/en/latest/reference/content-types/media_selection.html) there is none, but maybe there is still a way?

Reason is, that I want to allow to add an image to a text, but only one.

Maybe:

```
 <property name="image" type="media_selection">
     <param name="maxSelectionAmount" value="1"/>
 </property>
```

Comment: Sorry @Andreas there is currently no plan to implement this in 1.6 series - but this will be part of 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing like that at the moment... What we have implement in the alphas of 2.0 is that the is a separate `single_media_selection` content type. This works well for limiting the assigned medias to one but still doesn't allow to restrict to an arbitrary number.